# web application stopped working after change of service account

Tags: service-account

Web application is running with NetworkService Account. However, when I change to a domain account. The web application stopped working. It doesn't accept the user id anymore and keep prompting me with NTLM logging box.

Changing the account back to network service works again. I am not sure what is the problem. I tried to check ULS but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

Once you change the service account you have to make sure following things.

- new service account have DBO rights on the content dB and also have permission on configuration db.
- account should be part of iiurs_user groups on the sharepoint server
- object cache settings configured properly(super user n super reader account)
- perform iisreset on all server
- if using kerberos authentication then configure the SPN for new service account.

Comment: Hi Waqas, i think when you change service account via central admin, all these things are taken care and that's the reason why ms doesn't recommend changing of accounts ast application pool level directly. Anyways, I have checked all these settings again and they are correct. No idea why i can't login. Changing security back to Network security service account works perfect. Nothing is captured in ULS also.. No idea what to do